Dynamically subtract two column values based on the filter selected and select a band on the basis of the value - Power BI DAX
We need to plot graph on Power BI where on X axis we have a band and on y axis we have count of customers that fall in this band
We have a front end filter having values Type1 , type2, type3 (Note: This filter has multi select option enabled)
When any of the type is selected ,TotalValuebyCustomer(Column D) should be subtracted from the selected type column.
Here is our table:

When Type1 is selected
For C01 ColumnD - Column E  i.e; 15-5 =10 Band should be 6 to 10 .
For C02 ColumnD - Column E  i.e; 16-1 =15 Band should be 10+
Graph should show 1 customer in 6 to 10 band and 1 customer in 10+ band
When type2 is selected
For C01 Column D- Column F i.e; 15-10=5 Band should be 1-5
For C02 Column D- Column F i.e; 16-12=4 Band should be 1-5
Graph should show count of 2 customers in 1-5  band
When type3 is selected
For C01 Column D- Column G i.e; 15-13=2 Band should be 1-5
For C02 Column D- Column G i.e; 16-10=6 Band should be 6 to 10
Graph should show 1 customer in 1 to 5 band and 1 customer in 6 to 10 band
When Type 1 and Type2 both are selected
For C01 Column D -[ColumnE + Column F] i.e; 15-(5+10)=0 Band should be 0
For C02 Column D- [ColumnE + Column F] i.e; 16-(1+12)=3 Band should be 1 to 5
Graph should show 1 customer in 0 band and 1 customer in 1 to 5 band
Expected Output:

Sorry, this post is a little wordy and hard to follow. Perhaps insert a few more graphs for visualization of what you are trying to accomplish (even just a mockup) and what you have?

what if category has different values? e.g. C01 A1 type 1 is 10, A2 type 1 is 15. what's the expected output?

Hey @Ryan. This could not be the case, Type 1, type2, Type3 value will remain constant for a single customer.
1 Customer will have a single value in Type1, Type2 and Type3 .
Let me know if any further details are required. I hope I was able to explain it correctly.

I missed your expected output. Could you pls provide the sample data (not the table visual)?

The image attached in my question is actually the input table

you can try this

select type 1 ,2 and 3 and unpivot columns


then we will have a band table

at last, you need to create a measure
MEASURE =
VAR _list =
    DISTINCT ( 'Table'[Attribute] )
VAR _list2 =
    DISTINCT ( 'Table'[Category] )
VAR _tbl =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE (
            FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[Attribute] IN _list && 'Table'[Category] IN _list2 ),
            'Table'[Customer],
            'Table'[Category],
            'Table'[Total ValuebyCustomer],
            "total", SUM ( 'Table'[Value] )
        ),
        "result", [Total ValuebyCustomer] - [total]
    )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            _tbl,
            [result] >= MAX ( Band[Left] )
                && [result] <= MAX ( Band[Right] )
        )
    )







Hey @Ryan , A little update, we cant exclude column B and C , Because column B value is another filter . When value A1 from column B gets selected and Type1 is selected , it should do 1-5

update the answer , pls have a try

I think if we select multiple values from any of the two filters. it goes wrong
